# SwiftUI's rotationEffect modifier has different behavior going clockwise versus counter-clockwise

Tags: swiftui, view, rotation, modifier

### Context

I have a subView consisting of an HStack containing (1) a line (Shape) and (2) a Text View. I want to rotate this subview, exactly like a rotating compass with a line going to the label "N". The `rotationEffect` modifier seems like it should do that for me. However, toggling the rotation from 0 degrees to 90, then toggling it back from 90 to 0, gives distinct behaviors.

### Initial Rotation

The View opens with the line and label horizontal. Changing the rotation angle to -90 degrees animates the line as it pivots counter-clockwise (as expected). However, the Text field does not rotate in sync with it. Instead, the Text field seems to move off of the display and only reappears at the end of the animation. The Text is re-oriented to the vertical (as expected) but it is no longer at the end of the line.

### Rotation Back

This unexpected behavior goes away when the rotation angle changes back to zero. This change causes the label to jump to the end of line (where it ought to be) and then the line and label animate, in sync, back to horizontal (as expected).

### Question

Any ideas on how to address the unexpected behavior?

The code is shown below:

```
import SwiftUI

// shows a line and Text that can be pivoted through 90 degrees
// with animation.
struct TestRotatingLineAndLabel: View {
    
    @State var angle = Angle.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            LineAndLabel()
                .rotationEffect( angle, anchor: .bottomLeading )
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0),
                                      value: angle)
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Change Angle") {
                angle = ( angle == Angle.zero )
                        ? Angle( degrees: -90.0 )
                        : Angle( degrees:  0.0)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct LineAndLabel: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            SimpleLine()
            Text("A Label")
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleLine: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            
        var path = Path()
        path.move( to: CGPoint( x: 0, y: rect.height ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: rect.width, y: rect.height ) )
        return path
    }
}
struct TestRotatingLineAndLabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestMovingLabelAnimation()
    }
}
```

Comment: In this kind of problem try with smaller angle value like 5 or 10 degrees. It can help to see what is wrong. Also temporarily add border do your view si you can see the limits. Rotation is not always as straightforward as we think due to coordinate systems and anchor positions.

Comment: See my findings here https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/SwiftUI_rotationEffect_LineAndLabel.md

Comment: Petit Xav, thank you! I would gladly set this as an “answer” but it doesn’t appear that you can do that for comments. If you add a response then I can flag it.